# How to solve SPOJ DISQUERY?

Tags: tree, lowest-common-ancestor

The problem is based on Lowest Common Ancestor concept.
It requires finding the length of shortest and longest edge in the path between a pair of nodes in a tree.

Here is the link to the problem: [SPOJ DISQUERY](http://www.spoj.com/problems/DISQUERY/)

Comment: You should show us your work.

Comment: Actually I thought of saving minimum and maximum edge in the same form as the 2^j th parent is stored in 2-d array using Dynamic Programming approach but using it how can I get the required answer was the issue for me...

Answer (score 3):

Finally I have done it myself.

It is asked in the question to find out the length of **shortest** and **longest** edge in the path between a given pair of nodes in a weighted tree.

For answering the query regarding **LCA** of given nodes(let a,b), we first precompute P[i][j], which is 2^j th parent of i using dynamic programming approach( you can find it [here](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/range-minimum-query-and-lowest-common-ancestor/) ).

During the same precomputation we can also calculate the length of **shortest** and **longest** edge in the path between the node and its 2^j th parent as follows:

> maximum[i][j] = max( maximum[i][j-1] , maximum[ P[i][j-1] ][j-1]);
>   
>  minimum[i][j] = min( minimum[i][j-1] , minimum[ P[i][j-1] ][j-1]);

Then first we can find the LCA of the given nodes (a,b) and then find the corresponding values of shortest and longest length edge using a loop from a to LCA and from b to LCA.

Finally we can find shortest and longest by just finding minimum and maximum once again....

For any doubt you can refer my code:

[Spoj DISQUERY SOLUTION](http://ideone.com/fyUapN)

`

```
/*
    Author:-Sarthak Taneja
    saar2119@gmail.com
    CSE 2nd year,MNNIT Allahabad
*/
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

typedef long long ll;
typedef pair< int,int > ii;
typedef vector< ii > vii;

#define sfd(x) scanf("%d",&x)
#define sfs(x) scanf("%s",x)
#define sff(x) scanf("%lf",&x)
#define mod 1000000007
#define MAX 1000000
#define pb push_back
#define mp make_pair
#define fr first 
#define sc second
#define testcases scanf("%d",&t);while(t--)
#define ffor(a,b,c) for(a=b;a<c;a++)
#define rfor(a,b,c) for(a=b;a>=c;a--)

int parent[100005]; // for keeping immediate parent of a node
int P[100005][18]; // for keeping 2^j th parent of a node
int maxi[100005][18]; // for maximum length from node to its 2^j th parent
int mini[100005][18]; // for minimum length from node to its 2^j th parent
int level[100005]; // for assigning levels to the node taking 1 as the root always
int root=1;
bool visited[100005]={0}; 
vector< pair<int,int> > graph[100005];

void setLevels(int node, int l,int dist)
{
    level[node]=l;
    visited[node]=1;
    if(dist != -1)
    {
        maxi[node][0] = mini[node][0] = dist; 
    }
    for(int i=0;i<graph[node].size();i++)
    {
        if(!visited[graph[node][i].fr])
        {
            parent[graph[node][i].fr] = node; // setting parent of a node
            setLevels(graph[node][i].fr, l+1, graph[node][i].sc);
        }
    }
}

int lca(int p, int q)
{
    int tmp,lg,i;

    if(level[p] < level[q]) // if p is above in level then p is swapped with q
        tmp=p, p=q, q=tmp;

    for(lg=1; (1<<lg) <= level[p]; lg++);
    lg--;

    for(i=lg;i>=0;i--) //bringing p and q to the same levels 
    {
        if(level[p] - (1<<i) >= level[q])
        {
            p=P[p][i];
        }
    }

    if(p == q)
        return p;

    for(i=lg;i>=0;i--) // finding lca of p and q by jumping both p and q
    {
        if(P[p][i] != -1 && P[p][i] != P[q][i])
            p=P[p][i], q=P[q][i];
    }

    return parent[p];
}

ii cal(int a,int b) //function to calculate the pair of maximum and minimum from a to its 2^j th parent b using a log(n) loop 
{
    ii pp;
    int lg,i;
    pp.fr=INT_MIN;
    pp.sc=INT_MAX;

    for(lg=1; (1<<lg) <= level[a]; lg++);
    lg--;

    for(i=lg;i>=0;i--)
    {
        if(level[a] - (1<<i) >= level[b])
        {
            pp.fr = max(pp.fr, maxi[a][i]);
            pp.sc = min(pp.sc, mini[a][i]);
            a=P[a][i];
        }
    }

    return pp;
}

int main()
{
    int i,j,t;
    int n;
    int u,v,w;

    {
        scanf("%d",&n);

        for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            graph[i].clear();
            visited[i]=0;
        }

        for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
        {
            scanf("%d%d%d",&u,&v,&w);
            graph[u].pb(mp(v,w));
            graph[v].pb(mp(u,w));
        }
        root=1;
        parent[1]=-1;

        for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<18;j++)
            {
                P[i][j]=-1;
                maxi[i][j] = INT_MIN;
                mini[i][j] = INT_MAX;
            }
        }

        setLevels(root,0,-1);

        for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            P[i][0]=parent[i];
        }

        for(j=1;(1<<j)<=n;j++) // dynamic programming loop to assign values of 2^j th parent and maximum and minimum length upto them
        {
            for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
            {
                if(P[i][j-1] != -1)
                {
                    P[i][j] = P[P[i][j-1]][j-1];
                    maxi[i][j] = max( maxi[i][j-1], maxi[P[i][j-1]][j-1]);
                    mini[i][j] = min( mini[i][j-1], mini[P[i][j-1]][j-1]);
                }
            }
        }

        int a,b,k;
        ii pp;
        ii qq;
        sfd(k);
        while(k--)
        {
            scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
            int lc=lca(a,b); //finding lca of a,b

            if(lc == a)
            {
                pp=cal(b,lc);

                printf("%d %d\n", pp.sc, pp.fr);
            }
            else if(lc == b)
            {
                pp=cal(a,lc);
                printf("%d %d\n", pp.sc, pp.fr);
            }
            else
            {
                pp=cal(a,lc);
                qq=cal(b,lc);
                pp.fr= max(pp.fr, qq.fr);
                pp.sc= min(pp.sc, qq.sc);
                printf("%d %d\n", pp.sc, pp.fr);
            }
            //that's it if you have any doubt you can ask it in the comments on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36083410/how-to-solve-spoj-disquery
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

In idea: you can do a BFS from either of the nodes (considering them as the root of the tree) until you find the other node, then you have the path (you should have built the tree with every node referencing its parent) and then, you only need to find the longest and shortest edge of the path.

Comment: Actually each query has to be answered in O(log n), so BFS is not possible in my opinion...